# How to combine single and multiindex Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate multiple Pandas DataFrames, some of which use multi-indexing and others use single indices. As an example, let's consider the following single indexed dataframe:

```
> import pandas as pd
> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'single': [10,11,12]})
> df1

   single
0      10
1      11
2      12
```

Along with a multiindex dataframe:

```
> level_dict = {}
> level_dict[('level 1','a','h')] = [1,2,3]
> level_dict[('level 1','b','j')] = [5,6,7]
> level_dict[('level 2','c','k')] = [10, 11, 12]
> level_dict[('level 2','d','l')] = [20, 21, 22]
> df2 = pd.DataFrame(level_dict)
> df2

  level 1    level 2    
        a  b       c   d
        h  j       k   l
0       1  5      10  20
1       2  6      11  21
2       3  7      12  22
```

Now I wish to concatenate the two dataframes. When I try to use `concat` it flattens the multiindex as follows:

```
> df3 = pd.concat([df2,df1], axis=1)
> df3

   (level 1, a, h)  (level 1, b, j)  (level 2, c, k)  (level 2, d, l)       single
0                1                5               10               20          10
1                2                6               11               21          11
2                3                7               12               22          12
```

If instead I append a single column to the multiindex dataframe `df2` as follows:

```
> df2['single'] = [10,11,12]
> df2

  level 1    level 2     single
        a  b       c   d       
        h  j       k   l       
0       1  5      10  20     10
1       2  6      11  21     11
2       3  7      12  22     12
```

How can I instead generate this dataframe from `df1` and `df2` with `concat`, `merge`, or `join`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid converting the single index into a `MultiIndex`.  This is probably the easiest way, you could also convert after joining.

```
In [48]: df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c, '', '') for c in df1])

In [49]: pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1)
Out[49]: 
  level 1    level 2     single
        a  b       c   d       
        h  j       k   l       
0       1  5      10  20     10
1       2  6      11  21     11
2       3  7      12  22     12
```

Comment: Thank you @chrisb! I had hoped for a simpler more generalizable approach, but I was able to formulate a workaround with your solution here that meets my needs

Answer (score 3):

If you're just appending one column you could access df1 essentially as a series:

```
df2[df1.columns[0]] = df1.iloc[:, 0]
df2
  level 1    level 2     single
        a  b       c   d
        h  j       k   l
0       1  5      10  20     10
1       2  6      11  21     11
2       3  7      12  22     12
```

If you could have just made a series in the first place it would be a little easier to read. This command would do the same thing:

```
ser1 = df1.iloc[:, 0] # make df1's column into a series
df2[ser1.name] = ser1
```