# Way to combind single and multi index dataframes without multi indexing the single index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a clean and simple way to combine a multi index and single index dataframe?

There are questions asking similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47561694/python-pandas-how-to-concatenate-a-multiindex-dataframe-with-a-single-index-dat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446698/how-to-combine-single-and-multiindex-pandas-dataframes) but both are old and have "messy" solutions.

I have a single index datafame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'single': [10,11,12], 'double': [7,8,9]})

   single  double
0      10       7
1      11       8
2      12       9
```

And I want this to be combined to a a series of multi index dataframe with empty columns that have different column and sub column indexes:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['happy'], ['very', 'not_much']]))    
Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [(happy, very), (happy, not_much)]
    Index: []
```

Then next itteration I will add this to the combine two dataframes above, and so on:

```
df3 =pd.DataFrame(columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['sad'], ['always', 'never']]))
    Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [(sad, always), (sad, never)]
    Index: []
```

I have tried both append and concatenate but get thir error for both:

```
TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
```

The end goal would be to get a dataframe looking like this:

```
                     happy              sad  
 single   double  very  not_much  always  never
    0      10       7
    1      11       8
    2      12       9
```

Comment: I think it is not possible, join Multiindex and `simple` index without convert both to `MultiIndex` or tuples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `concat` and then post_process the columns:

```
resul = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1, sort=False)
resul.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [('', i) if isinstance(i, str) else i for i in resul.columns])
```

It gives the expected:

```
                happy             sad      
  single double  very not_much always never
0     10      7   NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN
1     11      8   NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN
2     12      9   NaN      NaN    NaN   NaN
```